# Can anyone tell me what does App Time State mean?

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

I see these lines on debug console when I'm running a flutter project. I don't know what does this mean!

```
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=810.91ms min=48.64ms max=1573.17ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=16.33ms min=4.63ms max=397.50ms count=43
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=127.37ms min=6.54ms max=1381.83ms count=14
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=326.54ms min=16.72ms max=2680.73ms count=9
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=58.64ms min=6.86ms max=508.78ms count=21
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=490.05ms min=473.01ms max=520.80ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=515.16ms min=509.86ms max=520.45ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=497.41ms min=467.42ms max=527.65ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=492.27ms min=483.67ms max=508.95ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=514.45ms min=506.48ms max=522.43ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=489.61ms min=469.20ms max=501.75ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=507.12ms min=500.00ms max=514.24ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=494.44ms min=475.46ms max=517.95ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=501.36ms min=479.50ms max=523.22ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=515.68ms min=498.73ms max=532.63ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation( 6547): app_time_stats: avg=494.28ms min=477.78ms max=503.71ms count=3
```

I've change my emulator to one which has Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know it is impossible to remove these logs, you can filter in your logcat writing this in find search field:
!D/EGL